# Issues flatening objects after upgrade to Automapper 10.0

Tags: .net-core, automapper

After upgrade from Automapper 9.0 to 10.0 I've started to get ***System.ArgumentException**: 'Field 'AutomapperSandbox.Level2.TheField' is not defined for type 'AutomapperSandbox.Level1''*

My source object is:

```
    public class Level1
    {
        public Level2 FieldLevel2;
    }
    public class Level2
    {
        public long TheField;
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public string Id;
        public Level1 FieldLevel1;
    }
```

My destination object:

```
    public class Destination
    {
        public string Id;
        public long TheField;
    }
```

The mapping:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(
                    cfg =>
                    { cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.FieldLevel1);
                      cfg.CreateMap<Level1, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.FieldLevel2);
                      cfg.CreateMap<Level2, Destination>();
                    });
```

When running mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source), the exception is raised.
I've tried other approches without success.

This behaviour an issue introduced in Automapper 10.0? There is any issue in my code?

Thank you,

Carlos Marcão

Comment: Workaround: `cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.FieldLevel1.FieldLevel2);`.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it worked. I've tried a small variation adding an additional level(a class Level3). Even with your suggestion, the automapper raise the same error.

Comment: That's the whole point of the workaround, to avoid the extra levels :)

Comment: cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.FieldLevel1.FieldLevel2.FieldLevel3); This code raise the same exception

Comment: Do you think that it is an Automapper 10.0 problem?

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: Lucian, with that pre-release it works properly. Lets wait for the official release of 10.0.1.

Comment: Again, the workaround works for me, just use one `IncludeMembers`, not two.